# Laravel CRUD error on Selecting data from Database

Tags: laravel, crud

I am just developing a Laravel CRUD application with the following code

Student.php (controller page)

```
class Student extends BaseController
    {
    public $restful=true;

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('student.index')
        ->with('students',Student::all());
    }
}
```

Student.php (Model page)

```
class Student extends Eloquent
{
   public static $table='students';
}
```

index.blade.php (View page)

```
 <h1>Student home page</h1>
 <ul>
   @foreach($students as $student)
     <li>{{ $student -> name}}</li>
   @endforeach
 </ul>
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('test',array('uses'=>'student@index'));
```

the i point to browser like localhost/laravel/public/test

it shows error like

```
Method [all] does not exist.
```

i have table like namely 'students'
and fields are

```
 - id
 - name
 - class
 - division
```

any one please help me...

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method [all] does not exist.

Comment: have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: no..is it needed for running

Comment: yes - after you make new classes (like models) etc - you need to run it.

Comment: Command "dump-autolod" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?
    dumpautoload,
    dump-autoload

Comment: check your spelling - you've spelt it incorrectly. But any of those commands will work, they all do the same thing. Same as `composer dump` - same thing.

Comment: k. it showing "Generating autoload files"

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicated your "Student" class names for both your controller and model, so Laravel is getting confused. You should change your controller to `StudentController` to avoid the conflict

```
class StudentStudent extends BaseController
```

Dont forget to also update your routes file

```
Route::get('test',array('uses'=>'StudentController@index'));
```

Comment: then chage the $table to $table1

Answer (score 0):

You should create you controllers using the command line tool: php artisan

Use the following command in your terminal:

```
php artisan make:controller StudentController --resource
```

This will create a controller file with boilerplate code in app/Http/Controllers/StudentController.php

If you want just a blank controller then don;t add the --resource part

You can get a complete CRUD functionality here if you need to know more
http://deepdivetuts.com/basic-create-edit-update-delete-functionality-laravel-5-3